# dropdown menu in table cell in react.js

Tags: reactjs, html-table, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

I am implementing a table in react.js which has a dropdown menu in a cell. in the last row the dropdown menu is opening inside the table but the requirement is it should come out of table component instead of getting confined.

[here is the image to show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFZh8.png)

here is the link to the code [here is the link to the working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-poincare-6n83n5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.